# Joining a multicast stream via RTSP using ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, multicast

I have a `RTSP` server that provides access to a **multicast** stream. I can play it fine in `VLC` and various other players, however in `ffmpeg` / `ffplay` I get no data back.

After investigation this seems to be caused by the `RTSP` `SETUP` listing only **unicast** as a transport method.

If I use:

```
ffplay -rtsp_transport udp_multicast rtsp://<blah>
```

then it works fine.

How does `ffmpeg` decide which transport methods to put into its `SETUP` call? Is it perhaps some part of the `SDP` returned by the `DESCRIBE` call? Ideally I'd like to find a way to allow `ffplay` to play the multicast stream without the need to force the transport mode.

Comment: What RTSP server are you using? Can you post the contents of the SDP?

Comment: Did you get any answer for this query? I am facing the same issue. I am playing a RTSP Urls which contains TWO streams but ffplay is playing just one stream.